# SVG variable text

Tags: svg

I know little about SVG but I'm trying to make the text parameter variable, so I could iterate and create SVG Markup's which vary solely by (variable) text. This is what I can do (borrowed from the site whose API I'm using)

```html
'<svg  width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
  '<rect stroke="black" fill="${FILL}" x="1" y="1" width="22" height="22" />' +
  '<text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" ' +
  'text-anchor="middle" fill="${STROKE}" >hello world
  </text></svg>'
```

But this is what I would like (or something that works like it):

```html
'<svg  width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
  '<rect stroke="black" fill="${FILL}" x="1" y="1" width="22" height="22" />' +
  '<text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" ' +
  'text-anchor="middle" fill="${STROKE}" >"${TEXT}"</text></svg>'
```

so I can dynamically change the text.

Comment: Are you running into some problem?

Comment: Indeed the problem is I can't use "${TEXT}" it doesn't work (it not being embedded in a angle bracket I guess). Whereas I can dynamically change ${FILL}, for example, using .replace, I can't do so with the text...

Comment: i8 I figured it out 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I figured it out; in retrospect, it was kind of a stupid question . Just replace the faulty ${TEXT} tag with `+ varName +` like in normal string concatenation:

```html
var svgMarkup = '<svg  width="24" height="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' +
  '<rect stroke="black" fill="${FILL}" x="1" y="1" width="22" height="22" />' +
  '<text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" font-weight="bold" ' +
  'text-anchor="middle" fill="${STROKE}" >'+ varName +'</text></svg>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You actually **can** use `${TEXT}`, and it does work (except for IE).

The name of this is [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions.

However, for this to work, you should have enclosed the whole string with back-ticks (`).

Here is a working demo using your string (with little changes):

```js
var FILL = "tan", STROKE = "black", TEXT = "Hello World";

var svgMarkup = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100" height="24" 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect stroke="black" fill="${FILL}" x="1" y="1" 
width="22" height="22" /><text x="12" y="18" font-size="12pt" font-family="Arial" 
font-weight="bold" text-anchor="start" fill=${STROKE}>${TEXT}</text></svg>`;

var div = document.getElementById("foo");
div.innerHTML = svgMarkup;
```

```html
<div id="foo"></div>
```